# Create Indicator List in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, status, kpi

How do you create a KPI `Indicator List` as required by the `Status List` (Business Content) Web Part?

[image]

[This article](http://www.sharepointcrux.com/Blog/Post/7/Creating-Status-List-and-Status-List-Indicator-in-SharePoint-2013) suggests they're no longer supported (but link to MS site is broken). The article also provides a possible workaround - but it seems unnecessarily complicated. Given the `Status List` web-part is still there, why isn't the KPI `Indicator List` still available?

Comment: You can try to use jslink feature to get the kpit indicator functionality : [JSlink ](http://www.abelsolutions.com/2013-blog/creating-a-simple-kpi-column-in-sharepoint-2013-list-views-using-js-link/)

Comment: Thanks, but we have a end-user that's used to using `Indicator Lists`.